# JAVAFX 2.2 Calling a JavaFX page from Java Application

Tags: javafx-2

I have a JAVA FXML page which I am using to create a window and I have to call this window from a Java Swing Application. How can I do this?

My first page is a Java class, from where I need to start the window made with Java FXML page.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**: Use JFXPanel

```
         final JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
         frame.add(fxPanel); // your Swing frame

         Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
                 fxPanel.setScene(scene); // scene of you FX app
             }
         });
     }
```

**Option 2**: 
Run `javafx.application.Application.launch(YourFxApplication.class);`

Although latter approach is not recommended for Swing applications.